# Can't open lib '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server}' : file not found (0) al intentar conectarse a una base de datos

Tags: python, pyodbc

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos, pero me lanza un error.

Estoy ocupando la librería pyodbc para conectarme a una base de datos.

```
!pip install pyodbc
```

```
import pyodbc
```

```
server = ###
bd = ###
usuario = ###
contrasena = ###

conexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER= {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server}; SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+bd+';UID='+usuario+';PWD='+contrasena)
```

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib ' {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server}' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: ¿Ya has instalado [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#version-17)?

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente revisar el administrador de origen de datos ODBC, en la pestaña Controladores si tienes ese controlador, si no lo tienes, realizar la instalación.

Yo generalmente utilizo la siguiente configuración con el nombre del controlador mas general.

```
conexion = pyodbc.connect(
        "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
        "SERVER=" + server + ";"
        "DATABASE=" + bd + ";"
        "UID=" + usaurio + ";"
        "PWD=" + contrasena + ";",
        autocommit=True
    )
```